# Visual Studio Code extensions disappeared after changing the name of my PC

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code extensions disappeared after changing the name of my PC, and the extensions automatically get uninstalled now. I have an `extensions` folder in my `.vscode` folder, but they aren't showing up in VSC.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling vsc but it doesn't work and the extensions still won't stay installed. I changed "My PC" name to a name with no spaces because I kept getting this error:

> Name in the package.json file has illegal characters" error

After changing "My PC" to a name with no spaces, then that error went away but now my extensions are gone.

Comment: Do you have your settings synced to a Microsoft or GitHub account? It's pretty straightforward to get them back if you do.

Comment: Yes I have my settings synced to a Microsoft account

Comment: Check whether you're still logged in and synced with that account then.